# Do previous lines calculated influence the sequential lines in a loop for R?

Tags: r, loops

I have this code

```
x=c(T,T,F,T,F)

for (i in 1:5){
  if(i > 1 & i < 5){
     x[i ] = x[i-1] & x[i+1] & x[i]

     print(x)
  } 
  else if(i < 5){
     x[i] = !x[i] | !x[i+1]
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out the output it gives me

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I am wondering if the first value `x[2]` (which is `x[2] = T & F & T`) will influence the output of the next line `x[3]` or if these calculations for each line are independent of each other?

Comment: Don't start a new line between `}` and `else`. It will cause trouble outside a loop or a function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code mutates `x` in the for loop:

```
x=c(T,T,F,T,F)

for (i in 1:5){
  cat(paste0("\nLoop iteration Nr. ", i, " 'x' is: ", paste0(x, collapse=", ")))
  if(i > 1 & i < 5){
    cat(paste0("\nAbout to set x[", i, "] to ", x[i - 1] & x[i + 1] & x[i]))
    x[i] = x[i - 1] & x[i + 1] & x[i]

  } else if(i < 5){
    cat(paste0("\nAbout to set x[", i, "] to ", !x[i] | !x[i+1]))
    x[i] = !x[i] | !x[i+1]
  }
}

Loop iteration Nr. 1 'x' is: TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
About to set x[1] to FALSE
Loop iteration Nr. 2 'x' is: FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
About to set x[2] to FALSE
Loop iteration Nr. 3 'x' is: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
About to set x[3] to FALSE
Loop iteration Nr. 4 'x' is: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
About to set x[4] to FALSE
Loop iteration Nr. 5 'x' is: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
```

And since you use in each iteration the preceding value to calculate the current value, the i-th step influences the i+1-th step.

Comment: so then why does ```x[1]``` stay false for all the inputs because the second line would then be```x[1] = !F or !F.``` which is ```x[1] = T or T``` so ```x[1]``` on the second line should be T

Comment: nevermind... I see. because we only calculate x[1] once, and its the first one to be calculated

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.